# Upgrading Dynamoid from 0.7 to 1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting the following error on migrating from Dynamoid 0.7 to 1.0.

**Error:**

> cannot load such file -- dynamoid/adapter/aws_sdk

The error arises at the line :

```
require 'dynamoid/adapter/aws_sdk'
```

Can any one help me figure out the issue.

Comment: Can you put more details? What do you mean by "migrating"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure looking at the GitHub code will reveal the problem.

https://github.com/Dynamoid/Dynamoid/tree/master/lib/dynamoid

... contains no adapter/aws_sdk

Check:

https://github.com/Dynamoid/Dynamoid/tree/master/lib/dynamoid/adapter_plugin

... for aws_sdk_v2